# Using "Rank()" Function I need to update the Rank based on the TotalMark but marks should not be Null

Tags: sql-server-2017

Using Rank() Function Updating the Rank to TotalMarks in null

[image]

Using Rank() Function Updating the Rank to TotalMarks is not null

[image]

I'm updating the Rank based on the TotalMarks. If the TotalMarks is not null the rank is updating but (here the issue is) it should not allow to update the Rank if the TotalMarks is null.

How to resolve this?

Comment: `CASE WHEN TotalMarks IS NOT NULL THEN RANK()...` maybe?

Comment: Yes, that is correct I was bit of pressure on my work that's why I'm not able to focus on the small line.

I'm fresher in the SOFTWARE WORLD...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `CASE` expression

```sql
CASE WHEN TotalMarks IS NOT NULL THEN RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TotalMarks DESC) END
```